# Can not receive value from a data-list

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I've tried countless ways now to receive the value of this data-list when the user clicks the button to pass the information to the APIs and return the data. I am trying to receive these country names to pass them to another API to receive the country code to pass into the others. I've tried everything my novice self knows, and I either get null or it throws an error because I tried to pass null to a variable I already stated was to be a string.

The HTML

```
<input
            name="countryText"
            list="countrySelect"
            placeholder="Start typing..."
            id="'countryList"
            type="text"
          />
          <datalist id="countrySelect">
            <option value="United States"></option>
            <option value="Afghanistan"></option>
            <option value="Albania"></option>
```

The data-list continues and every value is that of the respective country

Just one of the iterations of JS I've tried to collect the value

```
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', async () =>{
    textValue = textBox.value.toLowerCase();
    countryValue = countrySelect.value;
    console.log(countryValue);
```

And earlier in the code I collect that element by ID and assign it to countrySelect
`const countrySelect = document.getElementById('countryList');`

And yes I have seen solutions with JQuery but I have to do mine with vanilla

I've tried everything my novice self knows, and I either get null or it throws an error because I tried to pass null to a variable I already stated was to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, kept your toLowerCase in case you need it, provided that you have a already managed to grab the search button and put it in the variable searhBtn:

```
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  let country = document.querySelector('input[name="countryText"]').value.toLowerCase();
  console.log(country);
});
```

Some points:

- It seems unnecessary to have an id on the countryText input since you can grab it by name, both in js and in your css if needed.
- Unless you are going to fetch something - maybe you are (you mentioned API:s) - or do something else async/await you might not have to keep 'async' on the event listener function.

Comment: I'll be sure to give this a try when I get working on it again tomorrow and yes I have another JS that is handling all of my API calls and further in that same even listener is when I'm calling them. This value was just to get one of the params I needed for those functions! It's commented out right now as I have been trying to debug this. Those all have been functioning correctly. The project was even complete. I just wanted to use a data-list instead of select to be able to bring in an autocomplete-esque function natively in vanilla with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `id="'countryList"` to `id="countryList"`
looks like vanilla js is not getting the required `string` value. whereas `jQuery` already filters it

Answer (score 0):

id of the input is different from the value given in js.

input element id = 'countryList
id in the js = countryList

I have added a snippet with your code. please check

```js
var countrySelect = document.getElementById("countryList");

const searchBtn = document.getElementById('searchBtn');

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', async () =>{
    countryValue = countrySelect.value;
    console.log(countryValue);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vquery/5.0.1/v.min.js"></script>


<input name="countryText" list="countrySelect" placeholder="Start typing..."
            id="countryList"
            type="text"
          />
          <datalist id="countrySelect">
            <option value="United States"></option>
            <option value="Afghanistan"></option>
            <option value="Albania"></option>
           </datalist>
     <button id="searchBtn">Search</button>
```